# Ação para um botão emprestar no rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estou iniciando agora a pouco no ruby on rails e estou com uma duvida 
Preciso fazer uma biblioteca, criei e estou listando os livros, criei tbm um botão emprestar em cada unidade de livro e ai esra o meu problema quero fazer com que esse botão ao ser clicado ja leve pra a pagina de emprestimo o ID do livro, isso ate consegui fazer mas quando vou salvar o emprestimo ele da um erro.

Criei esse metodo:

```
def load_livro
      if params[:livro_id]
        @livro = livro.find(params[:livro_id])
      else
        @livro = livro.new
      end
 end
```

E chamei ele assim:

botão emprestar em  app/views/livros/index.html.erb:

```
<td class="col-xs-1"><%= link_to 'Emprestar', "/emprestimo/new/#{emprestimo.id}" %></td>
```

E na pagina de emprestimo usei assim:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :livro_id, :value => @livro.id %>
```

Nessa ultima linha de codigo que ocorreu o seguinte erro:

```
Undefined local variable or method 'livro'  did  you mean? livro_url
```

Trecho do codigo com erro linha 4:

```
3 <div class="form-group">

4   <%= f.hidden_field :livro_id, :value => @livro.id %>

5 </div>
```

Comment: No erro que vc colocou aqui, vc consegue pegar o número da linha e também colocar ela aqui pra gente? Vendo exatamente a linha de onde esse erro ocorre será bem mais fácil te ajudar

Answer (score 0):

O nome da classe sempre deve vir com letra maiuscula, exemplo: `Livro.find`,
por isso o erro `Undefined local variable or method 'livro'`

```
def load_livro
      if params[:livro_id]
        @livro = Livro.find(params[:livro_id])
      else
        @livro = Livro.new
      end
 end
```

Comment: Verdade cara, mas no meu projeto esta em maiusculo sim e pq copiei esse trecho de codigo aqui na mão msm e acabei errando.   vou ate editar agora.